# Disposal of Aqueous Magnesium Salts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, salt

Where can I find out where (specifically) aqueous magnesium chloride and aqueous magnesium bromide can be disposed? I was trying to find out whether solutions could be diluted and washed down the drain or if more specialist waste disposal was necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the UK material safety datasheet of Magnesium Chloride [here](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/sds/SIGMA/M8266)

> SECTION 13: Disposal considerations
> 13.1 Waste treatment methods
> Product
> Waste material must be disposed of in accordance with the national and local regulations.
> Leave chemicals in original containers. No mixing with other waste. Handle uncleaned
> containers like the product itself. See [www.retrologistik.com](http://www.retrologistik.com) for processes regarding the
> return of chemicals and containers, or contact us there if you have further questions.
> Notice Directive on waste 2008/98/EC

You may wish to search the material safety datasheet (MSDS) for your own region, but it sounds like you should be using specialist waste disposal contractors if you have anything more than small amounts of it.

Comment: If it is a couple of grams, you can wash your magnesium solution down the drain. Magnesium is often present in small amounts in mineral waters. If it is a couple of kilograms, you should proceed like Waylander recommends it.